Orange Pi Zero 2 fails to auto-recover from filesystem errors after power loss on Debian Bullseye
I have a debian bullseye installation on an Orange Pi Zero 2 SBC. That computer sometimes loses power. If I restart it after losing power, I'm getting the following error:
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/mmcblk1p1 requires a manual fsck
(initramfs)

Full output I get is:
Loading, please wait...
Starting version 247.3-7
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done
Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ...Scanning for Btrfs filesystems done.
Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/mmcblk1p1] fsck.ext4 -a -C0 /dev/mmcblk1p1
/dev/mmcblk1p1: recovering journal
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to re-open /dev/mmcblk1p1

/dev/mmcblk1p1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

fsck exited with status code 12
done.
Failure: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/mmcblk1p1 requires a manual fsck
(initramfs)

How can I avoid that or have the fsck be executed automatically so that the system always properly restarts after a power out?

The file system check is started automatically, with a flag that asks it to run noninteractively, perform some obvious repairs without asking, and bail out if it encounters more serious problems.
What you have is a more serious problem -- the first superblock is damaged.
You can manually run fsck /dev/mmcblk1p1 from the initramfs, possibly specifying a backup superblock by adding -b 32768 (which is a likely candidate where you can find one).

fsck command is used to check and optionally repair one or more Linux file systems. To force a fsck on bootup you create empty file called /forcefsck.
see:  linux-force-fsck for details.
But the best is to make sure you fix the reason of the power loss (use an UPS).
